# Dispay 3D video on the web without plugins

Tags: opengl, 3d, webgl

Here is a possibly unanswerable question...

How do I create a website capable of displaying 3D images on a 3D capable display/monitor without using plugins?

Ignore the issues of bandwidth as they are not an issue. I also wish to avoid the red/green effect (anaglyph) as they have many problems. I figure that I could simply display an 120Hz video but then how do I sync the left and right image up with the screen's timing?

Any help would be appreciated however 'impossible' is never an answer. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to mimic the red/green 3d effect. You'd pass the left and right eye images through a filter and then display them on top of each other, though I'm not sure how off the top of my head. If you could make the views transparent that might work.

You wouldn't need to display anything at 120 Hz or have any synchronisation or plugins.

Google Streetview uses this 3d mode.

Comment: there are many problems with the red/green effect (anaglyph) and I wish to avoid them. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Garrows - in that case you should have included that information in your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way a browser has access to the graphic adapter specific driver libraries. hence it is not possible to make a website even with a plugin. Not to mention that most graphic adapters cant handle windowed 3D frames except proffesional Quadro cards. Every other 3D capable card has to run under certain resolutions and full screen.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm really not sure that there's a good way to sync output with the screen refresh. This is because anything running in a browser is subject to the browser's compositing and rendering.

You may want to look into [WebGL](http://khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Main_Page)--it's essentially a subset of OpenGL intended to provide hardware accelerated graphics in the browser. It's also supported by all of the beta or upcoming versions of the major browsers. Unfortunately, without any syncing mechanism, I don't know of any way to support the polarization method of 3D.

Comment: The Angle project (which is the underpinnings of most webgl implementations) is currently working on stereo 3D. Here's a link to the thread: https://groups.google.com/group/angleproject/browse_thread/thread/ed5fb532eebb7a95